# Kafka Log compaction returns two records with the same key

Tags: apache-kafka

I am having a strange behaviour with log compaction in kafka. I have created a topic with the following configuration:

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper ... \
--create --topic myTopic \
--partitions 12 \
--replication-factor 3 \
--config "min.insync.replicas=2" \
--config "cleanup.policy=compact" \
--config "delete.retention.ms=100" \
--config "retention.bytes=-1" \
--config "segment.ms=100" \
--config "min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.000001" \
--config "min.compaction.lag.ms=10"
```

I send messages with the same key to the topic, and when the compation launches, it returns the last two message of this topic.

Example:

```
Writting message with key="1" and value="A" into topic "myTopic"
Writting message with key="1" and value="B" into topic "myTopic"
Writting message with key="1" and value="C" into topic "myTopic"
```

COMPACTION

print 'myTopic' from beginning

{"ROWTIME":1549444994905,"ROWKEY":"1","value=B"}
{"ROWTIME":1549444994905,"ROWKEY":"1","value=C"}

```
Writting message with key="1" and value="D" into topic "myTopic"
```

COMPACTION

print 'myTopic' from beginning

{"ROWTIME":1549444994905,"ROWKEY":"1","value=C"}
{"ROWTIME":1549444994905,"ROWKEY":"1","value=D"}

The same with segment.ms=60000

Any idea?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Before compaction Kafka determined the lowest offset position, that can't take a part in compaction (`firstUncleanableDirtyOffset`).

That position is calculate based:

- First unstable offset
- Active segment offset
- `min.compaction.lag.ms`

In your case `min.compaction.lag.ms` is very low, so the lowest offset position (that can't take part in compaction) is taken from Active segment. Because of that only one message can take part in compaction (ex. key=1, value=C), so there is nothing to do.

If you produce extra message with other key, it should compact your messages for `key=1`.

Notice: You also have to be aware of `segment.bytes` property, which determine segment's size. If messages are small compare to `segment.bytes`, they might be in Active segment and won't be compacted.